# Count number of consecutive grouped entries in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'd like to create and populate the following **No. of Entries in Curr.Status** field seen below using SQL (sql server).

```
ID          Sequence    Prev.Status Curr.Status No. of Entries in Curr.Status
9-9999-9    1           Status D    Status A    1
9-9999-9    2           Status A    Status A    2
9-9999-9    3           Status A    Status A    3
9-9999-9    4           Status A    Status A    4
9-9999-9    5           Status A    Status B    1
9-9999-9    6           Status B    Status B    2
9-9999-9    7           Status B    Status B    3
9-9999-9    8           Status B    Status A    1
9-9999-9    9           Status A    Status A    2
9-9999-9    10          Status A    Status C    1
9-9999-9    11          Status C    Status C    2
```

Is there an quick way using something like `row_number()` --this alone doesn't appear to be sufficient-- to create the field I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: What was the attempt you made? Please do share it.

Comment: On what fields this number is calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark the rows where status changes using `LAG` function, and use `SUM() OVER ()` to assign unique number to each group. Numbering within group is trivial:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID VARCHAR(100), Sequence INT, PrevStatus VARCHAR(100), CurrStatus VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('9-9999-9',  1, 'Status D', 'Status A'),
('9-9999-9',  2, 'Status A', 'Status A'),
('9-9999-9',  3, 'Status A', 'Status A'),
('9-9999-9',  4, 'Status A', 'Status A'),
('9-9999-9',  5, 'Status A', 'Status B'),
('9-9999-9',  6, 'Status B', 'Status B'),
('9-9999-9',  7, 'Status B', 'Status B'),
('9-9999-9',  8, 'Status B', 'Status A'),
('9-9999-9',  9, 'Status A', 'Status A'),
('9-9999-9', 10, 'Status A', 'Status C'),
('9-9999-9', 11, 'Status C', 'Status C');

WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG(CurrStatus) OVER(ORDER BY Sequence) = CurrStatus THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chg
    FROM @t
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(chg) OVER(ORDER BY Sequence) AS grp
    FROM cte1
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY Sequence) AS SeqInGroup
    FROM cte2
)
SELECT *
FROM cte3
ORDER BY Sequence
```

[**Demo on DB Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b38f229837ee0b74da25a8abf1f35c2f)

Comment: Thank you. With a few quick changes this solved my issue. It's quite helpful to know that 'Partition by r1 - r2' can be used for this sort of operation!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a Groups and Islands problem. there are plenty of examples out there on how to achieve this, however:

```
WITH VTE AS(
        SELECT *
        FROM (VALUES('9-9999-9',1 ,'Status D','Status A'),
                    ('9-9999-9',2 ,'Status A','Status A'),
                    ('9-9999-9',3 ,'Status A','Status A'),
                    ('9-9999-9',4 ,'Status A','Status A'),
                    ('9-9999-9',5 ,'Status A','Status B'),
                    ('9-9999-9',6 ,'Status B','Status B'),
                    ('9-9999-9',7 ,'Status B','Status B'),
                    ('9-9999-9',8 ,'Status B','Status A'),
                    ('9-9999-9',9 ,'Status A','Status A'),
                    ('9-9999-9',10,'Status A','Status C'),
                    ('9-9999-9',11,'Status C','Status C')) V(ID, Sequence, PrevStatus,CurrStatus)),
CTE AS(            
    SELECT ID,
           [Sequence],
           PrevStatus,
           CurrStatus,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Sequence]) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,CurrStatus ORDER BY [Sequence]) AS Grp
    FROM VTE V)
SELECT ID,
       [Sequence],
       PrevStatus,
       CurrStatus,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY [Sequence]) AS Entries
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `Sequence` is identity column then you can do :

```
select t.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by (Sequence - seq) order by Sequence) as [No. of Entries in Curr.Status]
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by [Curr.Status] order by Sequence) as seq
      from table t
     ) t;
```

else you need to generate two `row_numbers` :

```
select t.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by (seq1- seq2) order by Sequence) as [No. of Entries in Curr.Status]
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id order by Sequence) as seq1
             row_number() over (partition by id, [Curr.Status] order by Sequence) as seq2
      from table t
     ) t;
```